# MySQL - how to optimize query with order by

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am trying to generate a list of the 5 most recent history items for for a collection of user tasks.  If I remove the order by the execution drops from ~2 seconds to < 20msec.

Indexes are on

```
h.task_id
h.mod_date
i.task_id
i.user_id
```

This is the query

```
SELECT h.*
     , i.task_id
     , i.user_id
     , i.name
     , i.completed
  FROM h
     , i
 WHERE i.task_id = h.task_id 
   AND i.user_id = 42 
 ORDER 
    BY h.mod_date DESC 
 LIMIT 5
```

Here is the explain:

```
id  select_type table type  possible_keys  key    key_len   ref     rows    Extra
 1  SIMPLE      i     ref   PRIMARY,UserID UserID       4   const   3091    Using temporary; Using filesort
 1  SIMPLE      h     ref   TaskID         TaskID       4   myDB.i.task_id  7
```

Here are the show create tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `h` (
`history_id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`history_code` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`task_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
`mod_date` datetime NOT NULL,
`description` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`history_id`),
KEY `TaskID` (`task_id`),
KEY `historyCode` (`history_code`),
KEY `modDate` (`mod_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=185647 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `i` (
`task_id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`due_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`create_date` date NOT NULL,
`completed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`task_description` blob,
PRIMARY KEY (`task_id`),
KEY `name_2` (`name`),
KEY `UserID` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12085 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: It does take time to sort all that data and then provide the top five.

Comment: We don't know what the UserID key looks like, but presumably an index on some combination of (i.user_id,i.task_id) will be optimal

Comment: For future reference, note that as well as the EXPLAIN for the given query, questions about query optimisation ALWAYS require SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables.

Comment: If `user_id` and `mod_date` were in the same table, `INDEX(user_id, mod_date)` would help performance.

Comment: Show create added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INDEX(task_id, mod_date, history_id)  -- in this order
```

Will be "covering" and the columns will be in the optimal order

Also, DROP

```
KEY `TaskID` (`task_id`)
```

So that the Optimizer won't be tempted to use it.

Comment: Something unexpected happened.  I dropped the 'task_id' key and added the index(task_id, mode_date, history_id) as suggested.  It did not speed up the query.  But then I REMOVED the new index, and the query was lightning fast (< 100 msec).

Comment: Getting rid of the h.task_id is the significant part of this answer.  It forced the optimizer to use the h.mod_date key and that makes a HUGE difference.  Here is the explain:   

   id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key           key_len  ref  rows  Extra  
   1  SIMPLE          h          index  NULL                  modDate  5  NULL  5  
   1  SIMPLE          i          eq_ref  PRIMARY,UserID  PRIMARY  4  h.task_id  1  Using where

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the index on `h.task_id` so it's this compound index.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE INDEX TaskID ON h(task_id, mod_date DESC);
```

This may (or may not) allow MySql to shortcut some or all the extra work in your `ORDER BY ... LIMIT ...` request.  It's a notorious performance anti pattern, by the way, but sometimes necessary.

**Edit** the index didn't help. So let's try a so-called *deferred join* so we don't have to ORDER and then LIMIT all the data from your `h` table.

Start with this subquery.  It retrieves only the primary key values for the rows involved in your results, and will generate just five rows.

```
         SELECT h.history_id, i.task_id
           FROM h
           JOIN i ON h.task_id = i.task_id
          WHERE i.user_id = 42
          ORDER BY h.mod_date
          LIMIT 5
```

Why this subquery? It handles the work-intensive ORDER BY ... LIMIT operation while manipulating only the primary keys and the date. It still must sort tons of rows only to discard all but five, but the rows it has to handle are much shorter. Because this subquery does the heavy work, you focus on optimizing it, rather than the whole query.

Keep the index I suggested above, because it [*covers*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_covering_index) the subquery for `h`.

Then, join it to the rest of your query like this.  That way you'll only have to retrieve the expensive `h.description` column for the five rows you care about.

```sql
SELECT h.* , i.task_id, i.user_id , i.name, i.completed
  FROM h
  JOIN i ON i.task_id = h.task_id 
  JOIN (
             SELECT h.history_id, i.task_id
               FROM h
               JOIN i ON h.task_id = i.task_id
              WHERE i.user_id = 42
              ORDER BY h.mod_date
              LIMIT 5
       ) selected ON h.history_id = selected.history_id
                 AND i.task_id = selected.task_id
 ORDER BY h.mod_date DESC 
 LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I don't think that `userID` is in `h`.

Comment: Tried this.  Making a compound index on task_id and mod_date did not speed up the query.

Comment: The deferred join significantly improved the query speed.  Instead of 5-10 seconds, the query completed in ~0.5 seconds.  Thanks!